Is there any file size limit for langchain loader?
I use UnstructuredExcelLoader to load an Excel file which has the size over 45mb, the process keeps running over 16 hours and seems not to be completed. but when I try to load an Excel file which has the size about 200kb, it finished normally in 5 minutes. I wander whether there is any limit for the langchain loder or not.
My running environment: python 3.10.14, memory: 16Gb
Who can give some information about the limit of the langchain loader, and how to load a big file over 45mb?

if processing 200 KB takes 5 minutes and you process 45 MB with the same speed, the estimated runtime is ~19 hours

Yes, you are right. my loader process completed over 23 hours.
Maybe increase memory can improve processing time, for my loader process failed with memory error once.

It seems there is nothing limit for langchain loader itself.
It just takes a long time to run the process if the PC spec is low.
